# Is the set X perfect? Abbott 3.4.9

Tags: analysis, set-theory

I have been solving a problem similar to Abbott's 3.4.9.

> Let $(r_1,r_2,r_3,\dots)$ be an enumeration of the rationals. For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ let $\epsilon_n = \frac{1}{2^n}$. Define the set $Y$ as follows:
> \begin{equation}
>         Y = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_{\epsilon_n}(r_n) = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left( r_n-\frac{1}{2^n}, r_n + \frac{1}{2^n} \right)
> \end{equation}
> and let $X = \mathbb{R} \backslash Y$. Is $X$ perfect? If not, how can we modify the construction to produce a nonempty perfect set of irrationals?

I have been able to show that $X$ is a nonempty, totally disconnected, closed set consisting entirely of irrational numbers, but I am not sure how to go about deciding if $X$ is perfect. My inital thought was to see if there are $x \in X$ such that $x$ is not a limit point of $X$.

Answer (score 1):

A set is perfect if it is closed and has no isolated points. Let $x$ be an isolated point of $X$. Then there is an open interval $I$ around $x$ which does not intersect $X$. Now find a contradiction.

Comment: Doesn't this show that $Y$ is perfect? My question is if $X = \mathbb{R} \backslash Y$ is perfect.

Comment: @Ethan sorry I meant to write $X$. The proof boils down to the fact that every interval contains a rational number.

Comment: This is what I have: Assume $X$ is not perfect. Then $X$ contains an isolated point. That is, there is an $x \in X$ such that for some $\epsilon > 0$ we have that $(B_\epsilon(x) \cap X)\backslash \{x\} = \emptyset$. This implies that $B_\epsilon(x) \backslash \{x\} \subseteq Y$. Im not sure how to get a contradiction from here?